# Prove that $8.\overline{74}\in\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that $8.\overline{74}\in\mathbb{Q}$

My try ::

$8.\overline{74}=a/b\implies b 8.\overline{74}=a$

But in fact i don't know how to prove it, maybe someone will help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: $a=8.74747474...$, $100a=874.747474....$, so $99a=?$

Comment: aha!!! well thought!!

Comment: thanks !! this is very helpful! :)

Comment: You're welcome :) It pretty much applicable for all numbers of this type, that's why it's nice :)